# How to solve a scrolling misbehavior after doing Alt+Tab?

Tags: 18.04, scrolling

most of the time I do an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (switch windows), go from browser (chrome) to Visual Code and vice versa, mouse scrolling misbehaves, it jumps to somewhere in the page, either way down the current scroll position, or way up, any thoughts on what's going on?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807187 and https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608246  sadly not fixed at the time of this comment.

Comment: Thank you @RuHasha for sharing that link, probably in the future I'll be reporting those bugs if I don't find solutions for.

Answer (score 34):

Installing and running `imwheel` fixes the problem for me.

```
$ sudo apt-get install imwheel
$ imwheel
INFO: imwheel started (pid=80085)
```

You have to start it at every boot (or add it at the applications to start).
`pgrep -lf imwheel` to see if it's running ; you can stop it with `pkill imwheel`.

/!\ It disables the zoom by `Ctrl + wheel` in applications (Firefox, Chromium, LibreOffice, PDF reader...)
(Maybe a setting in imwheelrc could fix that)

Comment: To add to startup, go to 'startup applications' from the menu, then add an item.  Just use the command 'imwheel'.

Comment: Just wanted to explicitly thank you for providing a solution to this problem which drove me mad for weeks now.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me, this bug was driving me mad too...! I would up-vote mutiple times if I could!

Comment: to re-enable `ctrl + wheel`, see [here](https://github.com/freeplane/freeplane/issues/134)

Comment: By the way I don't have the bug anymore in Ubuntu 20.04, on X11.

Comment: I didn't have this bug on 20.04, but 22.04 introduced the bug. `imwheel` worked for me!

Comment: For me, it doesn't work, imwheel added some stuttering scroll, it seems to be because I'm using touchpad instead of mouse.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking for a solution, It's still an unsolved bug. But if you wonder why such a thing may happen, I think the reason is that scroll position is being unique for all windows, or it's being changed for all of them when you scroll. for example, if you scroll up in a window a little, then go to the other one and start scrolling, the bar jumps a little upper and starts moving from there, showing that scroll changes from the other tab are being applied to the new one too.

Answer (score 4):

What you described is still an unsolved bug. When scrolling in one window, its scroll is buffered and repeated in another window after `Alt+Tab`. As you exemplified, it happens between Chrome and VS Code.

Fortunately, there's a GNOME extension as a quick fix for that: [Alt+Tab Scroll Workaround](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5282/alttab-scroll-workaround/). Just activate it and it should solve the problem.

I developed this extension to, among other things, surpass the `imwheel`'s problem of scrolling "stepwise" while using a notebook touchpad.

Comment: Thank you for making this plugin. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795#issuecomment-1511474956

Comment: Happy to help, @saurabheights!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Chromium source code. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608246#c68 for steps to reproduce. There's a long discussion about this issue at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795 and the root cause is explained in an blog post https://who-t.blogspot.com/2012/06/xi-21-protocol-design-issues.html from year 2012 which explains that the *first* scroll event after switching windows should be ignored. GTK has this workaround implemented for all GTK apps, but Chromium uses custom implementation which is missing this workaround.

There has been comments that this doesn't happen with Wayland which makes sense because the design bug is in X11 XI protocol. And if you have NVIDIA GPU, then Wayland is not a good option because the NVIDIA drivers are often unstable on Wayland.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by logging in with configuration **Ubuntu on Wayland** instead of simply **Ubuntu**.
[Something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxsGw.jpg). Image quality is low but you'll get the point.

That means I use Wayland instead of xorg but changing file /etc/gdm3/custom.config does not seem to solve the problem as stated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795#issuecomment-363341071).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not too attached to GNOME, switching to Unity solves the scroll issue on the mouse & trackpad:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

**Source:** [https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/#:~:text=Switch%20from%20GNOME%20to%20Unity%20in%20Ubuntu%2017.10,option%20to%20switch%20to%20Unity](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/#:%7E:text=Switch%20from%20GNOME%20to%20Unity%20in%20Ubuntu%2017.10,option%20to%20switch%20to%20Unity)

---

To restore the natural scrolling and other trackpad features, also install synaptics drivers:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: Using cinammon, that is very similar to GNOME solves too.