# After scrolling on web and coming back to vscode screen jumps

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

Using ubuntu 18.04

Initially I was working in vscode. But when I go to a web page and scroll and comeback to vscode, screen jumps to a new position suddenly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve a scrolling misbehavior after doing Alt+Tab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075621/how-to-solve-a-scrolling-misbehavior-after-doing-alttab)

Answer (score 1):

This is a hot issue and is still not fixed.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28795

The workaround with imwheel worked for me. So install it and in the terminal `imwheel start`. It is extremely annoying, hope it works for you.

Comment: It works. But scrolling is annoying it jumps.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer from https://askubuntu.com/a/1306783/736431

If you are not too attached to GNOME, switching to Unity solves the scroll issue on the mouse & trackpad:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

**Source:** [How to Switch from GNOME to Unity in Ubuntu 18.04 and 17.10](https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/#:%7E:text=Switch%20from%20GNOME%20to%20Unity%20in%20Ubuntu%2017.10,option%20to%20switch%20to%20Unity)

---

To restore the natural scrolling and other trackpad features, also install synaptics drivers:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Comment: Unity is getting less attention in favor of promoting GNOME. Ironically GNOME bugs was the reason Unity was invented in the first place.

Comment: I just wanted to ask how much Unity is still maintained... I have read somewhere the other day that it's getting buggy enough (and also, insecure) to not worth the bother... (I don't know exactly where I read it; but on this site). Maybe the release for 18.04 is still in a better shape? On the other hand, really shame. For me 16.04 with Unity was so welcoming and friendly. I straight away lasted 4 years on it without a second thought. 20.04 with Gnome still frustrates me to significant extents after one month...

Comment: I'd prefer a direct solution instead having to change my whole OS around

Answer (score 1):

Still an issue with VSCode 1.6.9.2 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS...

Workaround implemented as GNOME Shell Extension:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795#issuecomment-1186616155
- https://github.com/lucasresck/gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-scroll-workaround