# When scrolling in App1, then alt-tab to App2, App2 jumps its scoll point in line with App1 scroll, and vice versa

Tags: window, scrolling, mouse-scroll, focus, mouse-pointer

I am on 18.04 and it has only recently started happening.

1. When mouse scrolling in 1st app (e.g. 1.5 pages of scrolling).
2. I then change to another app.
3. As I then go to mouse scroll in the 2nd app, the page now jumps (e.g. 1.5pages) about the same amount as the first app was been scrolled,
4. but then continues to function normally after that, i.e. it continues to scroll without jumping again.
5. Until i then change apps back to the 1st app again,
6. at which point the first app will jump a similar amount as the 2nd app was scolled (excluding the initial jump).
7. effectively imitating a somewhat synchronous behaviour between the 2 apps.

2 apps I am seeing this on consistiently is Chrome (haha) and VS Code (hahaha). (Apps created by my 2 favourite companies.)

1st Update: 
Further testing produces these behaviours:

1. **Chrome - VS Code**: happens even in this specific website with VS code actually in this edit windows :)
2. **Chrome - VS Code**, App1 if I scroll down, and then App2 I scroll up the jump is down.
3. **Chrome - VScode** App1 scoll up 4 scrolls then down 4 scrolls produces very little jump in App2
4. **Document Viewer** does act as App1, but **does not** jump as App2
5. **Libre Office** does act as App1, but **does not** jump as App2
6. Both **Chrome** and **VS Code** act as App2 when App1 is Document
   Viewer or Libre Offce.

Wow, this is a complex beast of a bug, Should it be posted here?
Is there a better place, it seems generic but to some apps and not others

2nd Update:
OK best testing yet:
When the 2 apps were on different screens there was no issue.
So I minimised 1 to a small window same screen above the other app and there was an effect.
So I minimise both to small windows side by side and there was no effect.
2 small windows over laping but the scroll areas not overlapping, no effect.
2 small windows and the scroll areas over lapping yes effect, **but only if the mouse pointer is located in the 2nd apps area.**

So the bug is:
Some apps when not in focus are scrolled when the mouse pointer is located above the scroll area of the out of focus app, even though the scroll is for an above in focus app.

**Can someone tell me what I should do with this info/bug?
Or is this a feature? :)**

3rd Update:
As long as my mouse is above the out of focus application(whole window) when I do the initial scroll, I can move the mouse to any number of scollable areas within said out of focus app, and jump any scrollable area without fail, but only the first area will jump, then everything works as normal... On those apps that allow the jumping behaviour.

BTW I recently restarted my machine.

Comment: similar issue:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1108452/touchpad-moves-scroll-point-when-switching-application-and-scrolling-there

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this, although it can have it's own problems (I can't remember where I found this).

```
sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Try that out and see if you can live with the results. It would need to be run each time you reboot (possibly logout/in).

Alternatively there is another possible workaround: [How to solve a scrolling misbehavior after doing Alt+Tab?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075621/how-to-solve-a-scrolling-misbehavior-after-doing-alttab)

Comment: The alternative worked for me. Upvoting.