# Ubuntu 18.04 scrolling jumps when alternating between windows

Tags: 18.04, display, scrolling

In 18.04.3, If I'm in a scrollable window (e.g., terminal) and scroll down a lot, then <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to another window (e.g., Chrome) and scroll in this other window, its scrollbar jumps to the bottom immediately.

This happens using a mouse or the touchpad.

How do I solve the jumping problem in the second window?

after running

`sudo lshw -C display && sudo lspci | grep -i vga`

I get

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
```

Edit: I found out that the problem doesn't occur when the second application is the terminal, or firefox. In fact, I believe this problem is exclusive for Google Chrome.

Comment: The problem could be in the 2d app, or in display drivers. 1) If you start w/ Firefox then switch to Terminal & scroll there, does Terminal jump to the end? 2()Which display driver & hardware is used? Please tell us the PC make & model#; only get the model# from the serial # sticker, as other 'models' don't let us see what hardware's used. 3) Please also run `sudo lshw -C display && sudo lspci | grep -i vga` in a terminal & copy its results into the question. Please click [edit] and add all that essential info to the original question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, click [edit].

Comment: Very related, with a seemingly popular answer: [How to solve a scrolling misbehavior after doing Alt+Tab?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075621/1157519)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently this bug also happens, for example, on Visual Studio Code, probably there is something wrong with X11, and it is reported by some users [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795), [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608246) and [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=807187). It is mentioned by some users in the first link that an alternative to Xorg is Wayland. What solved my issue was to use Ubuntu with Wayland.

Comment: Is any special ritual required to enable Wayland? I've tried with `vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, `WaylandEnable=true`, `systemctl restart gdm3`, unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 4):

It's been more than a while but unfortunately, the problem still exists. (Ubuntu 22.04)

Going through the related issue on vscode's github repo ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795)), I found a temporary fix for GNOME that worked for me. All you need is to install this gnome extension: [Alt+Tab Scroll Workaround](https://github.com/lucasresck/gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-scroll-workaround)

Hope someone will actually fix this issue since it's been bugging people for more than 5 years now.

Comment: finally a fix for this annoying and long-standing issue