# Chrome browser replaying external scroll events (Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198, Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, mouse-scroll

I'm experiencing an odd scrolling bug in the Chrome browser (`Version 114.0.5735.198 (Official Build) (64-bit)`) on Ubuntu (`Linux 5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 7 15:06:04 UTC 20 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

Specifically, after I scroll using a mouse in another application (like a Document viewer), Chrome will replay that exact same scrolling when I switch back to it and scroll at all with the mouse, even if I only scroll a little bit.

For example:

1. I open a PDF in a Document viewer app and scroll down a few pages using the mouse
2. I then switch to Chrome, Brave, or Opera.
3. As soon as I scroll at all in Chrome with the mouse, it will scroll down the exact same amount as I did in the Document viewer.

This scrolling replay only seems to happen after I've scrolled in another application with the mouse and then switch back to Chrome. Scrolling in Chrome first with the mouse works as expected.

The Firefox browser works as expected and does not seem to have this issue.

Things I have tried:

- Disabling smooth scrolling in Chrome
- Updating my Chrome browser version

None of these steps have resolved the issue. I'm wondering if there are any other solutions I could try, or if this is a known bug in Chrome. Any help would be appreciated! Let me know if you need any additional information from me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: https://github.com/lucasresck/gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-scroll-workaround
from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1442448/947764